# Is it possible to switch between numeric only and alpha-numeric input modes for a CEdit control?

Tags: c++, windows, input, mfc, cedit

I have some radio buttons that decide the type of input to be given to the `CEdit` control. By design, my CEdit control accepts numbers and characters.

Is there a way to limit this input to only numbers *only* when the user clicks on a provided radio button? Also, when the user clicks on the other option (i.e. alpha-numeric mode), is it possible to switch back?

I set up my `CEdit` control to accept alpha-numeric characters using Visual C++'s GUI (i.e. right click on the control -> Properties -> "Styles" tab -> select "Number").

**An example use case:**

1. User starts application.
2. User clicks on some button and this dialog with the `CEdit` control in consideration shows.
3. User is presented with radio buttons where the alpha-numeric button is selected by default (since this is the default mode set at design time).
4. User clicks on numeric.

At this point I want to restrict input to the `CEdit` control to only numbers. Similarly, after this, if the user clicks on the alpha-numeric radio button again, I want to remove that restriction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, use `CEdit::ModifyStyle()` to either set or clear the ES_NUMBER style.

So, to make it accept numbers only:

```
CEdit *pEdit = // get your control here ...
pEdit->ModifyStyle(0, ES_NUMBER);
```

And to revert to accepting all characters:

```
pEdit->ModifyStyle(ES_NUMBER, 0);
```